# Sherlock ActionBar Styles

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to style my action bar to have a background color throughout my application. Currently i use

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_top))
```

in each of my activities, but i want this to be globally defined. Secondly i don't want the icon in each activity ActionBar. How can this be achieved ?

### Kind Regards

Here is my Style. I want the title to remain but the icon to be hidden

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_top</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/bg_top</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To set the background color to be the same throughout your application, do the following:

In you AndroidManifest add the following style:

```
< application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme"
android:name=".MyApp" >
```

Then in your styles file add this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#ff3399CC</item>
    <item name="background">#ff3399CC</item>
</style>
```

You can then change the color or add any other styles.

Maybe this can help with the logo:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/actionbarsherlock/siirVdZw-ts

Comment: Sorry the first part worked. The icon thing dose not. I have edit my question to show whats going on .

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE !!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623805/actionbarsherlock-stacked-action-bar-styling-issue